# How can I get a JsonObject from a URL in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have to a JSONObject, especially the "data" content, in Android from a WebService, then I have to print it into a ListView or a Table.

This is my JSON:

```
{
    "status":200,
    "status_message":"Direct ways found",
    "data":[{"codice_linea":"5","partenza":"Longa","ora_partenza":"17:34:00","arrivo":"Schiavon","ora_arrivo":"17:38:00"}]
}
```

Comment: p.s: The key "data" of this JSON is an associative array (in PHP).

Comment: And what exactly is the question?

Comment: If you want to parse JSON in Android, use `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString)`, then use [methods of JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) to get to individual fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let

```
response = {
    "status":200,
    "status_message":"Direct ways found",
    "data":[{"codice_linea":"5","partenza":"Longa","ora_partenza":"17:34:00","arrivo":"Schiavon","ora_arrivo":"17:38:00"}]
} 


String status = response.get("status");       // status = 200
String status_message = response.get("status_message"); // status_message = "Direct ways found"

JSONArray message = response.getJSONArray("data");
            List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
              HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();

                JSONObject temp = message.getJSONObject(i);
                hm.put("codice_linea",temp.getString("codice_linea"));
                hm.put("partenza",temp.getString("partenza"));
                hm.put("ora_partenza",temp.getString("ora_partenza"));
               hm.put("arrivo",temp.getString("arrivo"));

                   ....................................
                   .............................

                 aList.add(hm);

            }
```

Finally all your JSON data is prased to `List aList`.

Then use custom `Listview` to show this data in `Listview`

Here is the full tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Hope this solved your problem.

Comment: Nice, thank you, but one more thing: "response" here JSONArray message = response.getJSONArray("data"); what is it? where does it come from?, How can I get the "response" with a URL like http://example.com?
Thank you again!

Comment: As you have array named data so in order to convert it into json you have to use getJsonArray

Comment: So "response" is a JSONObject type? Thank you

Comment: @L.Bedin Yes Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

I assume you effort to get this `Json` in android , if i right try this:

Paste your example `Json` in [Json Schema 2 Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) , and site will generate Pojo classes

Convert your `Json` response to `Pojo` class with `Gson`

Add this line to your dependencies : `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'`

Convert `Json` result to Pojo :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourPojo yourpojo= gson.fromJson(jsonresponse, YourPojo.class);
```

And handle result whatever you want .

**If you didnt effort anything**

Go to google and search how to handle Json in android or how to connect web service , for example you can search : `HttpUrlConnection` , `OkHttp`, `Retrofit` ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new org.json.JSONObject(YourJsonResponse);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("codice_linea");
    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("partenza");
    jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ora_partenza");
    ......

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you seem wanting to do is to re-create an existing JSONObject that is contained in an array.
If you use the JSONObject from the Android tools, you can use `getJSONObject` and `getJSONArray`.
According to the Documentation:

> Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONArray, or throws otherwise.
>
> Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONObject, or throws otherwise.

See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray(java.lang.String)) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like that:

```
         JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                        Your-url-JsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                            try {
                                // Parsing json object response
                                // response will be a json object
                                String status = response.getString("status");
                                String status_message = response.getString("status_message");
                               JSONArray jsonArray =jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                      for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("codice_linea");
        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("partenza");
        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ora_partenza");
 jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("arrivo");
 jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ora_arrivo");}

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            hidepDialog();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // hide the progress dialog
                            hidepDialog();
                        }
                    });

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
        }
```